# ionic 2 serve ignores changes in html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am starting an ionic2 project, and running into trouble with seeing changes in code reflect to the browser.

Description of the phenomenon:

At some point I  see all of what I expect to see in the browser. For example, a single page whose .html is

```
{{text}}
```

and text field in the .ts contains "hola".

The output is obviously `hola`.

Then, I either can change the .html to

```
Hello World!
```

Or the text field in the .ts to "mundo"

Since `ionic serve` is running in the background, I see the browser update itself after I save the change in the code.

However, it always updates to the same old `hola`.

Doesn't matter how many times I refresh, save, change. I can even delete all contents of both .html and .ts files, and still the browser would show the old state.

**things I tried that don't work:**

- clearing cache from chrome
- restarting `ionic serve`
- saving any and all files again
- refreshing browser.

It is very frustrating to work like this, as this problem comes and goes, and I have no clear method to even bypass it.

Any suggestions?

---

I run windows 10, and this happens both in chrome and firefox.

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "saperli",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.10.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.10.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.10.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.3.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and I had to switch to using Google Chrome Icognito mode. Caching of javascript seemed to mess things up in development.

Comment: Just tried it now, It happens in incognito as well. which part of the cache should I delete to reset this? just deleting the browsing history and the cached images and files did nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

First run in your project folder `npm run clean` to do a clean then `npm run build` to rebuild before serving again.

Comment: I tried it, then opened in incognito, and still didn't work

Comment: May be we are looking @ this wrong first post your html & ts